# What is considered too heavy for UserDefaults?

Tags: ios, core-data, swift4, cloudkit, userdefaults

I'm building a simple iOS app that will be the first I'll have put on Apple's App Store. At one point, the app accesses the user's contact list and lets them select any number of contacts they want to save as favorites.

For ease of building version one, I am currently using UserDefaults to save these favorites. While it has worked well in my limited testing, I know that Core Data and CloudKit are stable options for larger solutions.

For an app like mine, where I'm only using UserDefaults to save a select number of contacts as favorites, is UserDefaults an adequate solution? Or should I transition to something more robust like Core Data or CloudKit? There is no limit on the number of contacts a user could select as a favorite, so there is the edge-case possibility of a user selecting all of their contacts one by one and attempting to save them all as favorites.

If the user gets a new phone and loses all existing data due to UserDefaults being local on the device, it would not take long to get this app back to where they previously had it.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults) says "The parameters are referred to as _defaults_ because they’re commonly used to determine an app’s default state at startup or the way it acts by default." It is not, IMHO, the right place for any model objects, regardless of how "heavy" they are.

Comment: FYI, I might refer you to [iOS Storage Best Practices](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/fall2017/204/). Not only is the video good, but there are links to relevant documents there, too.

Comment: Both of those links are very much appreciated! I'll be watching the video on iOS Storage Best Practices tonight.

Comment: I would also look into using Realm for persisting data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CoreData to store favorite contact locally for large data as per your concern. Now when user switch device or delete app then all data will removed. So for that you can sync with cloudKit or other option is backend server. When user add any contact as favourite same time that contact will add to Core data as well as in backend server. You can sync this backend server data when user login first time in the app, then you no need to sync again. other all thing are as per requirement.